# How to pass listener from Fragment to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, android-dialogfragment

I have I `Fragment` that show `DialogFragment` .. The `DialogFragment` creates and shows a `TimePickerDialog` dialog.

I want the calling Fragment to implement the `imePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` listener. but I don't know how to pass this listener to the Called fragment (The DialogFragment) ..

I have found the following code that passes a listener from `ACTIVITY` to the `DialogFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;

    // This error will remind you to implement an OnTimeSetListener
    // in your Activity if you forget
    try {
        mListener = (OnTimeSetListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnTimeSetListener");
    }
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), mListener, hour, minute,
            true);
}
```

How to pass it from `FRAGMENT` ?

Comment: you can use interface as a callback the activity first. then communicate the time picked from activity to fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use getTargetFragment and setTargetFragment?

And then first check if the targetFragment is an instance of your Listener:

> if (getTargetFragment() instanceof OnTimeSetListener) {
>   mListener.updateTime(); }