# Passing a listener to a custom Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm creating a view pager in my app and using a class that extends Fragment on it. When I create an instance I can pass all the elements (an image, text, etc) and store it with the Bundle to use it in the onCreate. But I can't store a listener for the button in the fragment. Here is my class:

```
public class RegWizardFragmentInfo extends Fragment {

private static final String IMAGE = "image";
private static final String TEXT = "text";
private static final String BUTTON = "buttonText";
private View.OnClickListener buttonCallBack;

private Button button;
private int image;
private int text;
private int buttonText;


public RegWizardFragmentInfo newInstance(int image, int text, int buttonText, View.OnClickListener callback) {

    RegWizardFragmentInfo fragment = new RegWizardFragmentInfo();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(IMAGE, image);
    bundle.putInt(BUTTON, buttonText);
    bundle.putInt(TEXT, text);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    return fragment;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.image = getArguments().getInt(IMAGE);
    this.text = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt(TEXT)
            : -1;
    this.buttonText = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt(BUTTON)
            : -1;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    //Extract all the views and add the image and texts

    return rootView;

}
```

So, how can I store the listener that I get in the newInstance to add it to the button on the onCreateView method?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you define the OnClickListener in the fragment itself to handle clicks? I think it's bad practice to have any UI callbacks somewhere else than in the activity/fragment that hosts the UI.

Comment: @Headcracker I need it to be passed from the activity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338223/how-to-pass-listener-from-fragment-to-dialogfragment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a callback in your `Fragment`:

```
public class RegWizardFragmentInfo extends Fragment {

    private Button button;

    private OnClickCallback callback;

    public interface OnClickCallback {
        void onClick();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        callback = (OnClickCallback) context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callback.onClick();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and implement this new interface in your parent `Activity`

Answer (score 5):

The other answers assign the listener in `onAttach`. While this will work, it requires that the calling `Activity` (and not, say, an anonymous class) implement your interface. Moreover, it forces you to cast the `Context` given to you in `onAttach` to an instance of your interface, which can cause crashes and is generally considered bad form. You might instead create a method to set the listener inside your `Fragment`:

```
public class RegWizardFragmentInfo extends Fragment {

    private OnClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnClickListener {
        void onClick();
    }

    /**
     * Call at any time after this fragment has been constructed.
     */
    public void setListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    /* ...other stuff... */
}
```

I can think of three disadvantages to this approach:

1. You need to call an extra method every time you want to instantiate the `Fragment`.
2. You can't guarantee that `mListener` is set at any time. You may need to pepper your `Fragment` code with null checks.
3. You need to be careful to make sure the listener remains set after lifecycle events such as screen rotation.

Comment: But then you have no guarantee that the mListener will be set when you register it with the button.

Comment: @MattD at least when your activity is 1k LOC you're not spending time looking which ``@Override`` belongs to which interface, instead, you have a listener as a class field. IMO, better approach.

Comment: **UPD:** one month later I retract my argument. The solution does not survive orientation change. My advice: either go with not so good, but quick ``onAttach()`` solution casting context or opt to a better approach using ``ViewModel`` as it will survive orientation changes.

Comment: So to sum up : your solution is only good for applications that should crash at some point.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you want to re-use the `Fragment` with various different listeners. So your approach is not ideal since you can not use the `Bundle` for that. A better approach would be to use the callback design pattern e.g.

```
public class RegWizardFragmentInfo extends Fragment {

    public interface RegWizardCallback {
        void onClick();
    }
}
```

Your `Activity` would implement that interface. Since a `Fragment` only lives inside an Activity you can get the callback instance from it by using the lifecycle method `onAttach()`. It would look like this

```
public class RegWizardFragmentInfo extends Fragment {
    private RegWizardCallback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            callback = (RegWizardCallback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement RegWizardCallback ");
        }
    }

    public interface RegWizardCallback {
        void onClick();
    }
}
```

With that you can simply call `callback.onClick` inside the listener of the Button.

Comment: `onAttach(Activity activity)` is actually deprecated method.

Comment: @OscarCaballeroPozas It's deprecated for >= 23. You still need to use the Activity variance for lower sdk versions.

Comment: @OscarCaballeroPozas, Murat is correct. on the other hand, we can use **`public void onAttach(Context context) {}`** similar method also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem about passing listener to a custom Fragment. I have a good way.

Firstly you should create a Singleton Listener Holder. Like this:

```
object ListenerHolder {
    var listener: YourFragment.OnApplyFilterListener? = null
}
```

and in your fragment that pass the listener;

```
ListenerHolder.listener = this
```

and in your passed fragment;

```
var listener: OnApplyFilterListener? = null
listener = ListenerHolder.listener
```

and you can reach your listener with this way.